# How can I set different distance of each points in highchart timeline?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timeline

I saw Highchart's `timeline chart` that customize each point `dataLabel`.
I want to add `dataLabel` option to set different `distance` for each points(data). So I added option like below code.

But when I use this code, it looks like `distance` option is not working. all of the `dataLabel's` distance is same.

How can I solve it? Did I use something wrong?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'timeline'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            date: 'Some date',
            label: 'Event label',
            description: 'Description of this event.',
            dataLabels: {
                color: '#78f',
                borderColor: 'blue',
                backgroundColor: '#444',
                connectorWidth: 2,
                connectorColor: 'blue',
                distance : 80, // I add this option for different distance
                style: {
                    textOutline: 0
                }
            }
        },{
            date: 'Another date',
            label: 'Last event label',
            description: 'Description of third event.',
            dataLabels :{
                 distance : 20
           }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `distance` that is set for all data labels you can use `y` property:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            y: -50,
            ...
        }
    }, {
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            y: 120
        }
    }]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/femo49gn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.dataLabels.y